# Java: Decorator Pattern - reference to main abstract class

Tags: java, design-patterns, decorator

I have read [this article](http://www.java67.com/2013/07/decorator-design-pattern-in-java-real-life-example-tutorial.html) about the decorator pattern and I have one question.

This class inhertis from the abstract class `SandWichDecorator`:

```
public class CheeseDecorator extends SandWichDecorator{
    Sandwich currentSandwich;

    public CheeseDecorator(Sandwich sw){
        currentSandwich = sw;
    }

    @Override
    public String getDescription(){
        return currentSandwich.getDescription() + ", Cheese";
    }
    @Override
    public BigDecimal price() {
        return currentSandwich.price().add(new BigDecimal("0.50"));
    }
}
```

Why is the reference to the `abstract` class `Sandwich` `Sandwich currentSandwich;` in the `CheeseDecorator` class?

Wouldn't it be easier to put it into the abstract class `SandWichDecorator`?
And every class extending `SandWichDecorator` would automatically have the reference.

Comment: "Sandwich" is one word. It doesn't require a capital W.

Comment: It's not easier, It's so similar, because If you declare the Sandwich attribute inside the abstract class, You must to implement the constructor with this parameter in all sub-classes.

Comment: In the example given on that website, the class SandWichDecorator doesn't add anything useful. I'm not sure why the author bothered with it. You could just as well have CheeseDecorator extend Sandwich directly.

Comment: @David Pérez Cabrera: thank you, that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right. You can just have the `current` Sandwich in `SandwichDecorator`, like this:

```
public abstract class SandwichDecorator implements Sandwitch {

    protected final Sandwitch current;

    public SandwichDecorator(Sandwitch current) {
        this.current = current;
    }

}
```

But, actually, you don't need even `SandwichDecorator` class. You can just have an interface `Sandwich` and implement it. It's not worth to have an abstract class just for holding the "decorated" reference:

```
interface Sandwich {
    String description();
    float price();
}

class BasicSandwich implements Sandwich {
    @Override
    public String description() {
        return "Sandwich";
    }    
    @Override
    public float price() {
        return 4f;
    }    
}

class CheeseSandwich implements Sandwich {   
    private final Sandwich origin;
    public CheeseSandwich(Sandwich origin) {
        this.origin = origin;
    }
    @Override
    public String description() {
        return origin.description() + " , Cheese";
    }    
    @Override
    public float price() {
        return origin.price() + 1f;
    }   
}

//More implementations of Sandwich
```

You can use it like this:

```
Sandwich completeSandwich = new CheeseSandwich(new BasicSandwich());
```

Designing with interfaces is more flexible than with abstract classes. Every time you writes `extends` a little cat dies.

Comment: Thank you Héctor for your explanation. I tried my own example with a bit of 
Mustard and Mayonnaise and it worked just using an interface (I don't want to kill
little cats either :-)).

Comment: un decorador de bruja de arena?? :)

Answer (score 2):

Your suggestion is fine IMHO. 
It also matches the GOF original:
[decorator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)

When discussing patterns in general, it's important to remember that variants are acceptable, there's no "Pattern Police" to reprimand you for every tiny deviation (as long as it's well considered)... If it were me, I'd change some of the article's AbstractClasses to interfaces, and I still believe my design intent would be clear and acceptable.

Perhaps you can ask the author in the comments (though it's an old post). If I had to guess, I'd assume the author wanted to leave some flexibility in the "currentSandwich" declaration/location (like taking it from a threadLocal, putting together 2 sandwitches, etc), but such 'creativity' would ruin the generality and modularity - namely the freedom to wrap several decorators one over the other. I'd prefer my decorators to stick to a well-defined "currentSandwitch", in which case it's fine to adopt your idea.

Comment: Thank you Pelit Mamani, I much like the approach shown by Hector, using interfaces rather than abstract classes.

Answer (score 2):

The essence of the pattern is allowing new functionalities/altered behavior to be added to an object statically or dynamically without affecting the behavior of objects of the same class.

You leverage polymorphism to accomplish that. A base abstract class or an interface provides a "category" of objects to be passed as input and output for decorating.

This is just the way selected by the author to showcase the pattern and I agree with you that it could be leaner.

The example provided by [Hector](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3026283/h%C3%A9ctor) (without the SandwichDecorator class) is in my opinion a better implementation of the pattern for the example.

Comment: Thank you tmart for your explanation as well.